# Take screenshot from io.flutter.embedding.android.flutterview

Tags: android, flutter

I want to programmatically take screenshots from my FlutterView in Android.

When it was **io.flutter.view.FlutterView** I just use `getBitmap()`
But how can I make screenshot from **io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView** ?

I tried following code but this does not work:

```
private fun getBitmapFromNewEmbeddedFlutterView(flutterView: io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView): Bitmap {
     val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
             flutterView.width,
             flutterView.height,
             Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
     )
     val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
     flutterView.layout(
             0,
             0,
             flutterView.measuredWidth,
             flutterView.measuredHeight
     )
     flutterView.draw(canvas)
     return bitmap
 }
```